# Iterating queue of struct type in stl

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, queue

I have a simple example of a queue of the struct type.
Here is geeks ide link : https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/PDvXlup2Z6

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct Task{
    int pid;
    int days;
    int depend;
};

int main()
{
    int w,i,j,t,id,day,dep;
    cin>>t;
    Task task[t];
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        cin>>id>>day>>dep;
        task[i].pid=id;
        task[i].days=day;
        task[i].depend=dep;
    }
    //for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    //cout<<task[i].pid<<" "<<task[i].days<<" "<<task[i].depend<<endl;

    queue<Task> job_queue;
    //queue<struct Task>::iterator it;

    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
        job_queue.push(task[i]);

    cout<<"Queue size is: "<<job_queue.size()<<endl;
    /*for(auto it = job_queue.begin();it!=job_queue.end();it++)
    {
        cout<<*it->pid<<endl;
    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

I am facing problem in the iterating queue to print all its element,also how could I take specific element of queue content like `queue[i].id or queue[i].depend`? please help me as i dont know a proper syntax.
For the above code input:

```
4
1 2 0
2 4 1
3 7 0
4 12 1
```

Output: Queue size is: 4

Here is geeks ide link: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/PDvXlup2Z6

Comment: `Task task[t];` isn't valid standard c++. Use a `std::vector<Task> task(t);` instead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, But I could able to iterate task[t] to see its content

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, see the updated post for iterating the task

Comment: @rafix07, I need this container for making the task in the queue. But for debugging purpose, I wanted to iterate the queue, so asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to support you. It is good that you are getting more and more acquainted with the STL.

So, you would like to store elements in a FIFO, a “First In First Out” – Container. You checked the STL and found the std::queue most fitting. It has exactly what you need:

- front
- back
- push
- pop

So you selected std::queue as your container for your elements “Task”. Now, looking at your code, there are several steps of improvement possible, to come up with a modern C++ program.

First we need to eliminate a C++ syntax (and semantic) error. In C++ you cannot define dynamic plain arrays. The dimension of the array needs to be a compile time constant. So a real C++ compiler will not eat

```
Task task[t];
```

But fortunately C++ has a container that behaves similar like plain arrays, but can grow dynamically: std::vector.  You should prefer std::vector (or other containers) over plain arrays. The result is that:

```
std::vector<Task> task(t);
```

This will create a vector with t empty tasks.

Next optimization is the removal of temporary variables. In your input loop you can write:

```
cin >> task[i].pid >> task[i].days >> task[i].depend;
```

With that you can eliminate 3 temporary variables: id,day,dep
And, additionally you can also delete w and j. They are not needed.

Next step: A class or struct knows how its values should be read (or written). So you will overload the >> operator for your class Task. With that the start of your class will look lke this:

```
struct Task {
    int pid;
    int days;
    int depend;
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Task& task) { return is >> task.pid >> task.days >> task.depend;  }
};

int main()
{
    int t, i;
    cin >> t;
    std::vector<Task> task(t);
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        cin >> task[i];
    }

    . . . .
```

Already much better. Now the next and major problem and the answer to your question. For debug purposes you want to iterate over you job_queue. And you are asking:

> Iterating queue of struct type in stl

And the answer is: Not possible.

std::queue has no iterators and no index operator []. The reason for that is that std::queue is a wrapper around a different STL container. It is the intention of the std::queue to hide its “inner” values and allow only access to front and back. This is OK for your normal purposes, but not for your wish to access “inner” members in the debugging case. The solution is easy. Select a different container and in this case and for your purposes, a std::deque. Is has also your needed functions, e.g. front, back. The push and pop  functions have extended names, because there is a pop_front and a pop_back and a psuh_front and push_back. And, that is the point, it has iterators and an indexing operator []. Now you could make your program like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

struct Task {
    int pid;
    int days;
    int depend;
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Task& task) { return is >> task.pid >> task.days >> task.depend; }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Task& task) { return os << task.pid << ' ' << task.days << ' ' << task.depend; }
};

int main()
{
    int t, i;
    cin >> t;
    std::vector<Task> task(t);
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        cin >> task[i];
    }
    deque<Task> job_queue;
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++)
        job_queue.push_back(task[i]);

    cout << "Queue size is: " << job_queue.size() << endl;
    // Option 1
    for (i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
        cout << task[i] << '\n';
    }
    // Option 2, more C++
    for (auto it = job_queue.begin(); it!=job_queue.end(); ++it){
        cout << *it << '\n';
    }
    // Or, even better, taking C++ range based for
    for (const auto& taskref : job_queue) {
        cout << taskref  << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But that is not the end. In C++ you can use algorithms for everything. For input and output you can especially use std::istream_iterator and std::ostream:iterator and std::copy functions.

With that, and, this is maybe a final optimization, your program looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct Task {
    int pid;
    int days;
    int depend;
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Task& task) { return is >> task.pid >> task.days >> task.depend; }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Task& task) { return os << task.pid << ' ' << task.days << ' ' << task.depend; }
};

int main()
{
    int numberOfTasks{ 0 };
    std::deque<Task> jobQueue{};

    std::cin >> numberOfTasks;

    // Read all task values
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<Task>(std::cin), numberOfTasks, std::back_inserter(jobQueue));

    // For Debug purposes. Print job Queue
    std::copy(jobQueue.begin(), jobQueue.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Task>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

That is the "more-C++" solution.

I hope I could help you a little bit . . .

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got my solution:

```
for(i=0;i<t;i++)
        job_queue.push(task[i]);

    auto iter=0;
    int size =job_queue.size();
    Task temp;
    while(iter++ <size)
    {
        temp=job_queue.front();
        cout<<"Entry "<< temp.pid<<" "<<temp.days<<" "<<" "<<temp.depend<<endl;
        job_queue.pop();
        job_queue.push(temp);
    }
```